# How use parameter passed in Mixin (Jade)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, parameter-passing, mixins

We use 'mixin' and want to pass a parameter to the mixin to make different word labelling based on the parameter.  However in file 1, the 'mixGenderType" value is empty that the ng-show doesn't work.  Can I ask if there's anything wrong in it?

Thank you!

file 1

```
mixin gender-list(mixGenderType)
   div.col-sm-12.student-list
       ul.list-group(class=mixGenderType)
           li.list-group-item.card-actions
               a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm(ng-show="mixGenderType=='boy'",ng-click=mixSelect) Show/Hide male student &nbsp;
               a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm(ng-show="mixGenderType=='girl'",ng-click=mixSelect) Show/Hide female student &nbsp;
```

file 2

```
include ../listing/listing.jade
div.container-fluid
    h1 Boy
    +gender-list(
        'boy'
    )
div.container-fluid
    h1 Girl
    +gender-list(
        'girl'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be used in "" .

Maybe you need to use "if".

```
if mixGenderType=='boy'
    ....
else if ....
    ....
```